# delete function not working cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x ...i want to delete a single record from the database
 i have a table in my database called **Image** .. which contain following fields.. 
    idImage,User_id,filename,filesize,filemime

I would like to delete the single record with idImage=imageid

```
      delete * from posts where imageid = 3'
```

i am doing this ..image id now has a value 4

```
      $this->Image->imageId = $imageId;
if($this->Image->delete()){
        echo "successfull";
    }else{
            echo "not";
        }
```

but the code is not working .not deleting the record from db

Comment: where is it that you are defining `imageId`. If you echo or print `imageId` are you getting the correct value "4"?

Comment: i am getting a parameter from my view page into my controller function and i am successfully getting the id which is 4 ...

Comment: also, did you specify `imageId` as the primary key in the model? By default Cake will use `id` as the primary key. In your model write  `var $primaryKey = 'imageId';`

Comment: nope i didnt specify it .. ok let me try

Comment: i try but still didnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### id, not imageId

Setting `imageId` on the Image model will have no effect at all. If the model's primary key is not `id` it's necessary to [configure the model](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#primarykey) so that Cake is aware of this and will use your chosen primary key field instead of `id`.

```
<?php
class Image extends AppModel {
    $primaryKey = 'imageId';
```

Irrespective of the value of the primary key, the property to set to use the syntax in the question is:

```
$this->Image->id = $imageId;
if($this->Image->delete()){
```

This will attempt to delete the image with the given `$imageId`.

Alternatively just [pass it to the delete function](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html#delete):

```
if($this->Image->delete($imageId)){
```

### Deleting without a primary key

If the objective is to delete by a value that isn't the primary key, either look for it first:

```
$id = $this->Image->field('id', array('imageId' => $imageId));
if ($id && $this->Image->delete($id)) {
    ...
```

Or use [deleteAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html#deleteall):

```
// delete 1 or more records with a matching field value
$this->Image->deleteAll(array(
    'imageId' => $imageId
));
```

Comment: i have imageId primary key in my db and i have specified too in my modal